# How do I access the GRAPH API to get all users WITHOUT having to login ?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

What I want is simple but I have not found a clear answer.

I have a simple console app and all I want to do is get all the users in my Azure AD using the new GRAPH API. All the examples I have require the program login (OAuth?). I don't want that. I want to give the code the user/pw and simply start calling the methods.

Comment: Even you have user/passwd, Azure still need login authentication, try `UserCredential userCred = new UserCredential(User, Password);`

Comment: Do I need to 'Create an app' in Azure as well  ?

Comment: NO, just use user credential

Comment: Even if you use `UserCredential`, you still need to reference an application's `client_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the PowerShell script I wrote.

```
# Adding the AD library to your PowerShell Session.
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'

# This is the tenant id of you Azure AD. You can use tenant name instead if you want.
$tenantID = "<the tenant id of Azure AD>"
$authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID" 

# Here, the username must be MFA disabled user Admin at least, and must not be a live id.
$username = "<the username of the AD's Admin>"
$password = "<the password of the above user>"

# The resource URI for your token.
$resource = "https://graph.windows.net/"

# This is the common client id.
$client_id = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"

# Create a client credential with the above common client id, username and password.
$creds = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" `
                    -ArgumentList $username,$password

# Create a authentication context with the above authentication string.
$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" `
                    -ArgumentList $authString

# Acquire access token from server.
$authenticationResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resource,$client_id,$creds)

# Use the access token to setup headers for your http request.
$authHeader = $authenticationResult.AccessTokenType + " " + $authenticationResult.AccessToken
$headers = @{"Authorization"=$authHeader; "Content-Type"="application/json"}

# Get the users.
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantID/users?api-version=1.6"
```

If you are using C#, it would be really similar, because my script is actually translated from C# code. For other Programing language, there are similar APIs in the corresponding Azure SDK. If not, you might consider using OAuth2.

Comment: So I still 'Create an app' in Azure?  I don't just use a admin user/pw ? I am used to the old way of doing things so all these token/Oauth concepts are new to me. It looks to me I need both . Create the app and give it permissions in azure as well as log in. Ill give this a try and get back to you

Comment: This solution stores admin user's username and password in a script, which is generally considered a very insecure approach.

Comment: I will just have mine in code (dll). But it is not a very serious product. Just need it to work.

Comment: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

Comment: The link above also helped me

Comment: I have check the link you provided. It's exactly what I am using. As what I said above, my script is translated from C# code. And, If you don't like storing the user name and password in the script. You can use `Get-Credential` to prompt for them.

Comment: Besides the security risk, there are several other downsides to using Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow (that's the OAuth 2.0 flow invoked when using `UserCredential`): it won't work if the user is on a federated domain name (most large enterprises), it won't work if user needs to change their password, and it won't work if multi-factor authentication is enabled.

Comment: @punkouter Remember that it's not necessarily this application's security you're concerned with--it's the security of everything else that the admin's username and password could be misused to do (email, other applications, create/remove/promote users, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a user physically sitting at the device, your best bet, by far, is to invoke the full sign-in flow. Not only does keep an admin's credentials from being exposed, but it also allows the user to change password if needed, invoke multi-factor authentication, etc.

However, there are some scenarios where you want an entirely unsupervised service running on a completely secure and trusted machine. (Known as a "confidential client" in OAuth 2.0.) This can be achieved with the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant flow, which uses *only* the application's credentials to authenticate. This is illustrated in [Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx).

Using ADAL, this flow is invoked by using either [`AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken(String, ClientCredential)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479466.aspx) (where your credential is an password credential--a string), or  [`AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken(String, ClientAssertionCertificate)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt459145.aspx) (where your credential is a certificate that you use to sign an assertion). There is a .NET (C#) sample for each of these on the [Azure AD samples for daemon applications](https://github.com/azure-samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=active-directory-dotnet-daemon):

- [Calling web APIs in a daemon or long-running process](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon)
- [Authenticating to Azure AD in daemon apps with certificates](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential)

Using PowerShell and certificate authentication, it would look something like this:

```
$appId          = "<app client ID>"
$resource       = "https://graph.windows.net" # (or other resource URI)
$tenantId       = "<domain name or ID>"
$certThumbprint = "<certificate thumbprint>"

# Get locally-installed cert by thumbprint
$x509cert = Get-ChildItem "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" | ? { $_.Thumbprint -eq $certThumbprint } | Select-Object -First 1

# Get access token using ClientAssertionCertificate
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId"
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate $appId, $x509cert
$authContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext $authority
$authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resource, $creds)

# Make Graph API request to list all users
$header = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($authResult.AccessToken)"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $header -Uri "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantId/users?api-version=1.6"
($result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).value
```

You will need to ensure your application is registered in Azure AD, and has the minimum required application permissions for what you're trying to do (and not more than that, to limit your exposure if the app's credentials were to be compromised). For example, if your application only needs to read directory data (e.g. to find a user by email address), you would set the permissions like this:

[image: App-only permissions to read directory data]

Comment: In my case users are in an external program and my code occurs when they press a button. When the button is pressed I use the Graph API to send an email and match an email with a AAD user. I don't think it would make sense or even work with the user doing a Office365 login before this occurs.. Since they don't have the permissions (or maybe its the Azure app you set the permissions?) But maybe I am missing something

Comment: It really depends on what you need. The code @PhilippeSignoret provided require you to create an AD application with certificate, have the permissions properly configured, and your customer to install the certificate in their machines. And, it will not be able to create new applications to you AD. It will not be able to create new users either (if you are using b2c, this is not the case). It's more secured because you have full control on the permission of the AD application and the certificate.

Comment: @punkouter There are definitely are scenarios where you would want to call Azure AD Graph API in the app-only context, that's why the Client Credentials flow exists. And yes, when you configure the app, you would choose what permissions the app should have (I added a screenshot to my answer).

Comment: @JackZeng It is certainly possible to configure an application to create users, add other applications, etc. in the app-only context. (Whether or not that's a good design choice is a different subject.)

Comment: So what is the relationship between the AD account and the Azure application ? as far as what the code does... Does the code only care about using the user/pw to tell it that it is allowed to do that rest.. and then the app permissions from that point on is all the really matters?  hope that made sense..

Comment: When you are doing app-only authentication, there is no relationship between the user account and the application. The application acts as itself only. (In other flows, it's the combination of app + user that is "acting".)